# Чи можна уникнути неоднозначності при використанні слова "вживаний"?

Tags: вибір-слова, прикметники

Контекст: йдеться про річ, предмет, який був у використанні однією особою, а потім використовується іншою. Тобто, антонім до слова *новий*.

Еквіваленти в інших мовах <sub>англ.</sub> *used* або *second hand*, <sub>рос.</sub> *бывший в употреблении* або *б/у*.

Більшість словників [пропонують](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) варіант **вживаний, уживаний**. Такими словниками є "Російсько-український фразеологічний словник" (Підмогильний, 1927), "Російсько-український словник ділової мови" (Дорошенко, 1930) та інші.

Проблема полягає в тому, що слово *вживаний* також використовується у сенсі «той, який **є** у вжитку» або «той, що часто, постійно використовується». Навіть у нас на сайті постійно зустрічаємо вислови виду:

> «Слово X є більш **уживаним**, ніж слово Y»,
>   «Слово Z є **вживаним** на території…» тощо.

Зрозуміло, що це не те саме, що *second hand*. І найбільш неприємним є те, що контексти дуже подібні, і їх легко сплутати. Наприклад, у реченні *«я купив вживаний смартфон»* може йтися або про популярну модель або про пристрій, який був у використанні.

З іншого боку, варіанти на зразок *зажи́ваний* також виглядають незвично.

**Запитання:** чи є метод, завдяки якому можна уникнути такої неоднозначності? Це могло б бути інше слово, або службова частина мови тощо.

Comment: Чесно кажучи, не відчуваю двозначності. Для позначення не нових речей слово "вживаний" є усталеним. Тому ваш приклад із смартфоном сприймається мною однозначно. Коли ж під цим словом у наведеному прикладі розуміти "популярний" або "поширений" то така конструкція виглядає дуже дивною і незвичною для мене. На користь цього вказує пошук: використання слова "вживаний" в якості "поширений, розповсюджений", по-перше, дуже мізерне; по-друге, стосується в основному якихось, нематеріальних (?) речей ("останнім часом це дуже вживаний вислів/термін/мотив") та їжі, напоїв ("горілка дуже вживаний продукт")

Answer (score 1):

Якщо хочете позбутися двозначності, можна використовувати форму `"той, що був у вжитку"`. Таким чином, ця сполука слів набуває єдиного значення. Приклад:

> Я купив телефон, що був у вжитку.

Також в деяких ситуаціях використовується слово "старий" в залежності від контексту як еквівалент словам "подержанный" та "second-hand".